# Is there a way to add QoS to Gitlab Jobs that share hardware resources?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The scenario is: I have one piece of hardware to test, but multiple jobs that run within various, unrelated projects, all requiring that same hardware. The hardware has input settings that would not smoothly transition between applications and would require a reset of said hardware to reuse between jobs so timesharing is not possible. Does gitlab have a way to write Quality-of-Service (QoS) into your job proxy and yaml files for jobs that require the same resources (in this case hardware)? Besides some job staging detection, detection jobs within unrelated projects does not seem straight forward.

UPDATE:
This isn't ideal as it would be nice to apply QoS to the devices, but you can apply devices directly to a runner and use runners for specific pipelines, thus limiting contamination.

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    privileged = true
    devices = ["/dev/path/to/device"]
```